# Why "docker stack ps" is throwing an exception?

Tags: docker

I'm barely starting on docker and following the [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/#run-your-new-load-balanced-app). I followed until this step where `docker stack ps` is throwing me an exception(that's what I think) that the command needs exactly 1 argument. I don't understand what I should actually pass in there. I tried the `--help` but it is giving me some not so useful info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It expects the name of the application as the argument.

```
docker stack ps <application name>
```

How did you start the stack?

Comment: docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml getstartedlab. But this gives me the processes which are running inside the container, I believe.

Comment: What happens when you run docker stack ps getstartedlab? You can also try running docker stack ls.

Comment: It is listing the number of instances. I think I got it figured.